# locust does not work when I started worker node, because of failed to connect master node from worker node

Tags: python, locust

## What happened?

- locust does not work when I started worker node, because of failed to connect master node from worker node. the below is details.
- this problem occasionally happens.

```bash
$ locust -f /path/to/a.py --config=config/master.conf
[2022-10-25 17:56:34,618] PC-0003395.local/INFO/locust.main: Starting web interface at http://0.0.0.0:8089 (accepting connections from all network interfaces)
[2022-10-25 17:56:34,623] PC-0003395.local/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 2.12.2
```

```bash
$ locust -f /path/to/a.py --config=config/worker.conf
[2022-10-25 17:56:59,326] PC-0003395.local/WARNING/locust.runners: Failed to connect to master 127.0.0.1:5557, retry 3/60.
[2022-10-25 17:57:04,331] PC-0003395.local/WARNING/locust.runners: Failed to connect to master 127.0.0.1:5557, retry 4/60.
[2022-10-25 17:57:09,334] PC-0003395.local/WARNING/locust.runners: Failed to connect to master 127.0.0.1:5557, retry 5/60.
```

In this time, I have the below config files.

- master.conf

```
headless = false
master = true
expect-workers = 1
host = SOME_HOST
users = 1
spawn-rate = 1
run-time = 1m
```

- worker.conf

```
headless = false
worker = true
master-host = 127.0.0.1
```

## My environment

- OS

  - macOS Monterey version 12.4
- CPU

  - M1
- python / locust

  - `locust 2.12.2 from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/locust/2.12.2/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/locust (python 3.10.8)`

I don't know how to fix this problem except restarting my mac.
Please teach me how to fix this one.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks right in your setup. The only thing I can think of is macOS’s software firewall (the one that pops up and asks you something along the lines of ”is it ok for Python to receive incoming connections?”)

Try setting `master-bind-host = 127.0.0.1` in master.conf, that might help with that.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
I could fix this problem.

This problem is caused by Android Emulator.
Android Emulator uses the port between 5554 to 5682.
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

Sometimes the 5557 port may be used by Android Emulator.

It works after I kill Android Emulator process that listens on 5557 port.

But I think that if this thinking is right, locust master process could not start. it is unknown for me...

Comment: And I want to told you that locust is very very useful for us.
I'd like to take this opportunity to thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that should normally have been detected by the master process. Weird.